# In Swift 4, how can you assign to a keypath when the type of the keypath and value are generic but the same?

Tags: generics, swift4

Given:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar: String = “”
    var baz: Int? = nil
}
let values: [Any] = [“foo”, 1337]
let fooPaths: [PartialKeyPath<Foo>] = [\Foo.bar, \Foo.baz] 
let protoFoo = Foo()
```

How can I make a for loop that iterates through these keypaths and values, and assigns the values to the keypaths when the type matches for both and the keypath is writable?

Note: it must be done using generics, since Foo could have properties of any type whatsoever (except type Foo, of course).

I have tried stuff like:

```
func setKeyOnRoot<Root, Value>(_ root: Root, value: Value, key: PartialKeyPath<Root>) -> Root {
    var root = root
    if let writableKey = key as? WritableKeyPath<Root, Value> {
        root[keyPath: writableKey] = value
    }
    return root
}
```

But since value is necessarily cast as Any before calling this, the runtime fails to see the type Value as what it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This implementation is similar to what you provided as an example of an approach you tried, and I believe it produces the result you are looking for:

```
struct WritableKeyPathApplicator<Type> {
    private let applicator: (Type, Any) -> Type
    init<ValueType>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Type, ValueType>) {
        applicator = {
            var instance = $0
            if let value = $1 as? ValueType {
                instance[keyPath: keyPath] = value
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
    func apply(value: Any, to: Type) -> Type {
        return applicator(to, value)
    }
}

struct Foo {
    var bar: String = ""
    var baz: Int? = nil
}

let values: [Any] = ["foo", 1337]
let fooPaths: [WritableKeyPathApplicator<Foo>] = [WritableKeyPathApplicator(\Foo.bar), WritableKeyPathApplicator(\Foo.baz)]
let protoFoo = zip(fooPaths, values).reduce(Foo()){ return $1.0.apply(value: $1.1, to: $0) }

print(protoFoo)  // prints Foo(bar: "foo", baz: Optional(1337))
```

A version of this that does the same thing, but using a for loop as specified in the original question could replace the second-to-last line with:

```
var protoFoo = Foo()
for (applicator, value) in zip(fooPaths, values) {
    protoFoo = applicator.apply(value: value, to: protoFoo)
}
```

Note that some type erasure is needed to work with a single array of keyPaths that operate on the same root type but have different value types. However, at runtime, the closure inside `WritableKeyPathApplicator` can specifically cast to the correct original value type for each keyPath and either silently skip the value to set if it's the wrong type (as in the example code above), or it could throw an error or print more helpful information to the console, etc.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try it in the morning. Every time I tried things like this, ValueType is still “Any” inside the function. So the `if let` would always fail. But if by some magic your method does indeed work... tomorrow I will mark this correct and praise you in the name of Zeus!

Comment: Dude, this is pure genius. It works! Were you already using this for something, or did you just think of it out of the blue? Using a closure declaration to capture the type information context is just brilliant! Mind if I try to recruit you for a role?

Comment: @CommaToast - While I haven't used it for keyPaths before, this is a common pattern for Swift type erasers that I've used a lot in a variety of situations. It blew my mind the first time I saw this example of it a couple years ago :)  https://gist.github.com/JadenGeller/f0d05a4699ddd477a2c1

Comment: Now if I can just figure out how to do it before a Foo instance’s variables are initialized... LOL. Sigh