# How to simplify Swift array initialization

Tags: arrays, swift, keypaths

This is in reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47765972/8833459.
The following statement is given:

```
let fooPaths: [WritableKeyPathApplicator<Foo>] = [WritableKeyPathApplicator(\Foo.bar), WritableKeyPathApplicator(\Foo.baz)]
```

Is there an init or something else that can be done so that the following (or something similar) might also work?

```
let fooPaths: [WritableKeyPathApplicator<Foo>] = [\Foo.bar, \Foo.baz]
```

The original statement is just too much typing!  My "preferred" method currently gives the error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'WritableKeyPath<Foo, String>' to expected element type 'WritableKeyPathApplicator<Foo>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is unnecessary:

```
let fooPaths = [WritableKeyPathApplicator(\Foo.bar), WritableKeyPathApplicator(\Foo.baz)]
```

The second `Foo` is unnecessary.

```
let fooPaths = [WritableKeyPathApplicator(\Foo.bar), WritableKeyPathApplicator(\.baz)]
```

Also the first one if you do provide the type:

```
let fooPaths: [WritableKeyPathApplicator<Foo>] = [WritableKeyPathApplicator(\.bar),
                                                  WritableKeyPathApplicator(\.baz)]
```

If the major concern is typing, add a local typealias:

```
typealias WKPA<T> = WritableKeyPathApplicator<T>
let fooPaths: [WKPA<Foo>] = [WKPA(\.bar),
                             WKPA(\.baz)]
```